# What does this mean: The audio_session pod failed to validate due to 1 error! Flutter

Tags: xcode, flutter, android-studio, dart

I was working on my app and everything is fine, after i tried to export iPA for testing i got this error message as shown here:

[image]

I never seen anything like this error before, tried to clear flutter + xCode builds and still same, i even can't install/update Cocoa pods, tried to remove podfile.lock to generate a new one and still same error can't do anything at all

Any idea what is this and how to fix it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the solution,

I managed to fix it by delete & install the following files:

> Before you start, make sure to check your Flutter Doctor `flutter doctor -v` and resolve
> any issues if available.

Steps:

• Open your Flutter project -> delete pubspec.lock

• Go to your main project folder -> open iOS folder -> delete both podfile + podfile.lock

• Now open the terminal app (macOS)

• Copy & paste these command lines one by one and press enter after
each one:

1- `gem list`

2- `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods` (type Y and press enter if asked for confirmation)

3- `sudo gem install cocoapods` (this may take a while)

• Next, update and upgrade brew, press enter after each one:

1- `brew update`

2- `brew upgrade`

3- `sudo gem update`

• Last step, close your VS Code, Android Studio and re-open it, then
open the built-in terminal and type `flutter clean`

Now press the Pub Get button and build your app, it should work.